# Why we take snap shots in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra

Why we take snap shots in Cassandra ? see for example, the replication factor is 3 in a 4 node cluster, suppose 1 node goes down even though data is replicated remaining in 2 nodes right?

Comment: This is difficult to answer as a question, Are you asking about the C* Snapshot Procedure which stores hard links to sstables? Or about data replication and what happens during node failure?

Comment: Replicas don’t protect against someone dropping a keyspace.

Answer (score 5):

Backup in the distributed/replicated system is primarily for handling of following problems:

- Catastrophic failures - imaging that you had only one DC, and you lost all servers because of the some catastrophe that swept all servers
- Errors in application code, what if you deployed a new version of software, and it had error that changed the data, and you can't revert the changes
- Same for the human errors - what if your engineers issued commands to delete wrong partitions - that changes will be replicated to all servers
- ...

Answer (score 0):

You need to take snapshot while upgrading the Cassandra as well. I did it lot of time and can't imagine what my life would be without it.

Answer (score 0):

Snapshot also helps when one node having issue on sstables(sstbale corruption). you can restore that node from snapshot in very less time.